# Removing aggregates from ktable created by CogroupedKStream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, debezium

I'm working with Kafka Streams application where the messages are produced via Debezium postgres connector and I have a situation where I need to manipulate aggregates in a KTable. Here's a brief overview of my setup:

```java
        Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        
        KTable<String, Participant> participantsTable = builder.table(
            participantsTopic,
            Consumed.with(stringSerde, participantsSerde)
        );
        
        KGroupedStream<String, ParticipantTagging> taggingsStreams = builder.stream(taggingsTopic, Consumed.with(stringSerde, taggingSerde)).groupByKey();
        KGroupedStream<String, ParticipantAttribute> attributesStream = builder.stream(attributesTopic, Consumed.with(stringSerde, participantAttributeSerde)).groupByKey();
        KGroupedStream<String, ParticipantSource> sourcesStream = builder.stream(sourcesTopic, Consumed.with(stringSerde, participantSourceSerde)).groupByKey();

        final Aggregator<String, ParticipantTagging, ComposedParticipant> TAGGING_AGGREGATOR = new Aggregator<String, ParticipantTagging, ComposedParticipant>() {
            @Override
            public ComposedParticipant apply(String key, ParticipantTagging tagging, ComposedParticipant aggregate) {
                if (!tagging.isDeleted())
                    aggregate.tag_ids.add(tagging.tag_id);
                else {
                    Iterator<Integer> it = aggregate.tag_ids.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Integer tagId = it.next();
                        if (tagId == tagging.tag_id) {
                            it.remove();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return aggregate;
            }
        };
        
        final Aggregator<String, ParticipantSource, ComposedParticipant> SOURCES_AGGREGATOR = new Aggregator<String, ParticipantSource, ComposedParticipant>() {
            @Override
            public ComposedParticipant apply(String key, ParticipantSource source, ComposedParticipant aggregate) {               
                if (!source.isDeleted()) {
                    Iterator<ParticipantSource> it = aggregate.sources.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        ParticipantSource savedSource = it.next();
                        if (source.source_id == savedSource.source_id && source.source_type == savedSource.source_type) {
                            it.remove();
                            break;
                        }
                    }                    
                } else {
                    aggregate.sources.add(source);
                }
                return aggregate;
            }
        };

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

        final Aggregator<String, ParticipantAttribute, ComposedParticipant> ATTRIBUTES_AGGREGATOR = new Aggregator<String, ParticipantAttribute, ComposedParticipant>() {
            @Override
            public ComposedParticipant apply(String key, ParticipantAttribute attribute, ComposedParticipant aggregate) {
                if (attribute.isDeleted()){
                    aggregate.attributes.remove(attribute.attribute_id);
                } else {
                    try{
                        List<Object> deserializedAttribute = mapper.readValue(attribute.value, new TypeReference<List<Object>>() {});
                        aggregate.attributes.put(attribute.attribute_id, deserializedAttribute);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                return aggregate;
            }
        };

        KTable<String, ComposedParticipant> composedParticipants = sourcesStream.cogroup(SOURCES_AGGREGATOR)
        .cogroup(taggingsStreams, TAGGING_AGGREGATOR)
        .cogroup(attributesStream, ATTRIBUTES_AGGREGATOR)
        .aggregate(
            ComposedParticipant::new, 
            Materialized.with(stringSerde, composedParticipantSerde)
        );

        KTable<String, ParticipantRollup> participantsRollup = participantsTable.leftJoin(
            composedParticipants,
            (participant, composedParticipantData) -> {
                return new ParticipantRollup(participant, composedParticipantData);
            },
            Materialized.with(stringSerde, participantRollupSerde)
        );

        participantsRollup.toStream().to("composed-participants", Produced.with(stringSerde, participantRollupSerde));
```

In this setup, I'm using cogroup to combine multiple `KGroupedStreams` into a single `KTable<String, ComposedParticipant>`. This `KTable` is then joined with another `KTable<String, Participant>` to form a `KTable<String, ParticipantRollup>`.

My question is about managing the lifecycle of the aggregates in the composedParticipants table. Specifically, I am looking for a way to delete aggregates from this table under certain conditions. For example, if an aggregate becomes irrelevant(no data for each of 3 cogrouped entities) or its data is no longer needed(participant was deleted), I would like to remove it to prevent unnecessary resource usage and potential confusion.

I understand that Kafka Streams is designed to work with immutable data and that the concept of deleting might not directly apply. However, is there a recommended approach or pattern for effectively removing or ignoring certain aggregates in a `KTable`?

I tried using separate tables for each entity and then joining them using `outerJoin`, but the problem with old aggregates stays.